# How to run java code in a restricted sandbox (without network, filesystem access)

Tags: java, sandbox

Say some programmer gives me an executable jar (from Java code) along with the entry point to use. I want to run this jar (programmatically) from Java code in a restricted sandbox environment with no network or filesystem access or database access and a fixed amount of CPU and memory. I.e., the Java code should not cause any side effects on other programs running on the my jvm.

Ideally I would like to allow certain access based on situation (say for example, only files in a certain directory with quota).

Comment: Did you read this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867747/create-java-sandbox-based-on-security-policies

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**IMPORTANT — since Java 17 policy files and security manager have been deprecated and marked for removal**. [Here is a blog post explaining how to handle sanboxing post security manager](https://inside.java/2021/04/23/security-and-sandboxing-post-securitymanager/).

---

You can control the environment using policy files
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/PolicyFiles.html#Examples ([archived version @archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20130715074612/http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/PolicyFiles.html#Examples))

you could run then run your jar

`java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=/path/your_policy_file.policy -jar`

Comment: So is it possible to do as follows: run my program with full access and then load the jar programatically with restrictions

Answer (score 3):

This page describes the process in detail:

(archived)
http://web.archive.org/web/20160401020824/http://www.jayway.com/2014/06/13/sandboxing-plugins-in-java/