# What is the best way to execute sandboxed Java code?

Tags: java, security, sandbox, securitymanager

I am trying to reproduce an API for executing Java (like ideone.com has), but so far I'm having a lot of difficulties running Java sandboxed (SELinux sandbox doesn't work).

I've heard about the SecurityManager, but I'm trying to figure out what's the easiest way to run Java code in a sandbox (kind of like a Java applet running in the browser), instead of writing my own jail server using the SecurityManager.

Comment: what about this answer, seems like that's you need?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192493/how-to-run-java-code-in-a-restricted-sandbox-without-network-filesystem-access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the java-sandbox project [1] which aims at providing a simple interface to execute untrusted code.

[1] http://blog.datenwerke.net/p/the-java-sandbox.html

Answer (score 1):

The SecurityManager is designed for this purpose. You'll need to create a policy file to restrict access, as described here: [Policy Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html), then enable it at runtime for just the code you're trying to sandbox.