# how to run Java programs in a restricted sandbox

Tags: java, sandbox

I have been trying to build an online java compiler. But running the clients code on server raises many security issues.

There are few I can think of - infinite loops, Restricted access to API, limiting memory usage, etc.

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192493/how-to-run-java-code-in-a-restricted-sandbox-without-network-filesystem-access) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867747/create-java-sandbox-based-on-security-policies). But I have a few more questions.

1) Restricted access to API is possible with the help of policy tool. But how do I check on memory and cpu usage(infinite loops,..)?

2) Policy Tool provides options to give permissions and not to restrict. So, if I choose, "Runtime permission" and getStacktrace as target then all others would be restricted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Ideone API. You have certain restrictions for a free account but it relieves you the burden of handling security and all.

It is available as a webservice and its WSDL can be found here: ideone.com/api/1/service.wsdl

Answer (score -2):

One idea is to run the code on a separate thread. and kill that thread if it does not finish in a maximum allowed time.