# Securing untrusted java code

Tags: java, security

I have a server application that receives java code uploaded from its clients and then needs to be processed according to the method calls inside it.

My first thought was compile it - run it but when I thought about it well... ding ding security. How can I limit the calls that a specific code execution runs for example: it can do basic java jazz (for loops etc etc) access important classes like Math and access some methods from my server but without it being able to harm or do anything bad to the server.

Comment: Create a Java sandbox, look at here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715036/how-do-i-create-a-java-sandbox, here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867747/create-java-sandbox-based-on-security-policies and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502218/sandbox-against-malicious-code-in-a-java-application

Comment: I suggest rethinking the problem.

Comment: I think this question needs more clarity on what kinds of inputs it expects (is _any_ malicious code fair game?), what kind of system resources it needs to protect, and what kinds of system access it needs to (safely) permit the permited code to somehow access. You mention `Math`, but what are those "_other methods_" on your server?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define a policy at runtime, when running the uploaded code. As from Oracle's documentation on [Default Policy Implementation and Policy File Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html):

> **Specifying an Additional Policy File at Runtime**
>
> It is also possible to specify an additional or a different policy file when invoking execution of an application. This can be done via the "-Djava.security.policy" command line argument, which sets the value of the java.security.policy property. For example, if you use
>
> ```
> java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=someURL SomeApp
> ```
>
> where someURL is a URL specifying the location of a policy file, then the specified policy file will be loaded in addition to all the policy files that are specified in the security properties file.

You may use permissions inside that policy, to limit what the code can perform, such as:

```
permission java.io.FilePermission "/home/user/*", "read";
```

I hope this helps!